# Laravel array helpers if array has a value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an array has below returned from my blade :

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [AddOns] => Array ( [name] => Icann [type] => AddOns [value] => +20.00 [attributes] => Array ( [description] => Icann Fee ) ) ) 
[1] => Array ( [Package] => Array ( [name] => Domain [type] => Package [value] => +0.00 [attributes] => Array ( [description] => Domain Registration ) ) ) )
```

how can i check if value  `Icann` in `AddOns['name']` exists ie `AddOns['name']=Icann` and get its  `description` ie `AddOns['attributes']['description']` in my blade template ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> FROM QUESTION AUTHOR

I realized that `array_has()` did not acctually get the required value so
after searching i created a contract/interface with below method validator and used `@inject` in blade to access the interface class as below :

**method in interface**

```
public  function search_array($needle, $haystack) {

 if(in_array($needle, $haystack)) {
      return true;
 }
 foreach($haystack as $element) {
      if(is_array($element) && $this->search_array($needle, $element))
           return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```

**blade template**

```
  @inject('searchicann', 'App\Helpers\Contracts\RocketShipContract')
  @if ($searchicann->search_array('Icann', $array ))
     Found
  @endif
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the documentation [`array_has`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-array-has) helper should suite your needs.

> The array_has function checks that a given item exists in an array
>   using "dot" notation:
>
> ```
> $array = ['products' => ['desk' => ['price' => 100]]];
>
> $hasDesk = array_has($array, ['products.desk']);
>
> // true
> ```

Comment: `array_has()` checks for **ITEM** not value , in my senerio id like to see if value is actually that am looking for